# AndroidStudio 4 says enterPictureInPicture is depracated as of API 26 - this is incorrect, right?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0, android-picture-in-picture

AndroidStudio screenshot showing the warning:

[image]

Yet what I find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html) is:

```
Android 8.0 (API level 26) allows activities to launch in picture-in-picture (PIP) mode.
PIP is a special type of multi-window mode mostly used for video playback. It lets the
user watch a video in a small window pinned to a corner of the screen while navigating
between apps or browsing content on the main screen.
```

Nowhere can I find where this is now depracated. Am I missing something or is AS in error? I want to be sure I'm not coding down a dead path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enterPictureInPictureMode()` was introduced in API 24 and deprecated in API 26. It has been superseded by `enterPictureInPictureMode(PictureInPictureParams)`, introduced in API 26.

Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#enterPictureInPictureMode(android.app.PictureInPictureParams)

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {

```
   // Crear un objeto PictureInPictureParams
   PictureInPictureParams.Builder pictureInPictureParamsBuilder =
           new PictureInPictureParams.Builder();
   pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.setAspectRatio(new Rational(16, 9));
   pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.setSourceRectHint(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
   PictureInPictureParams pictureInPictureParams = pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build();

   if (isInPictureInPictureMode()) {
       return;
   }
   enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParams);
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).